# Error with Saving DataFrame to TFRecords in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tfrecord

I am trying to save dataframe to TFrecord file in spark-shell which need the dependency of spark-tensorflow-connector jar, so i run the

```
spark-shell --jars xxx/xxx/spark-tensorflow-connector_2.11-1.11.0.jar
```

then run the code below in spark-shell:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}

scala> val df = Seq((8, "bat"),(8, "abc"), (1, "xyz"), (2, "aaa")).toDF("number", "word")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int, word: string]

scala> df.show
+------+----+
|number|word|
+------+----+
|     8| bat|
|     8| abc|
|     1| xyz|
|     2| aaa|
+------+----+

scala> var s = df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("tfrecords").option("recordType", "Example")
s: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@da1382f

scala> s.save("tmp/tfrecords")
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class                             
  at org.tensorflow.spark.datasources.tfrecords.TensorflowRelation.<init>(TensorflowRelation.scala:29)
  at org.tensorflow.spark.datasources.tfrecords.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:944)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:763)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:944)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:396)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:380)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:269)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
  ... 70 more
```

the Spark version is 3.0.0 with Using Scala version 2.12.10 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_261)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Tensorflow connector compiled with Scala 2.11 (notice the `_2.11` part in the name of the jar) with Spark 3.0 that is compiled with Scala 2.12.

As of right now, there is no Tensorflow connector compiled for Spark 3.0, so you need to take Spark 2.4.6 that is compiled with Scala 2.11.

Comment: it succeed with Spark2 in another machine, thanks a lot!